# How to convert a data frame to extract only value columns and create a histogram?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
  X1 X2 X3 M1 M2 M3 Group
0                     1
1                     2
2                     3
3                     3
4                     5
```

I am interested to get just the indexes and associated groups so it looks like

```
Group Index 
1        0       
2        1            
3        2
3        3
5        4
```

Lastly if I can do a histogram to show how many counts of indexes come within each group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the pandas library?
If not, please do it, and start your script with:

```
import pandas
```

You don't need to get your index in a column to be able to count your occurences, here is the function to do it:

```
counting = your_dataframe_name['group'].value_counts()
print(counting)
```

For the histogram, you don't need 'counting' either, just use your data frame

```
your_dataframe_name.hist(column='group')
```